Series of functions - uniform convergence
I need some help with this exercise, we just started series of functions in class and I got stuck with this.
Let $( f_k) \subseteq F(\mathbb{R}; \mathbb{R}) $ be defined by
$
f_k(x) = \frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{x^2 + k}.$ Is the series  $\sum_{k=1}^\infty f_k(x)$ uniformly convergent on $\mathbb{R}$?
What I tried so far:
I have used the Weierstrass M-test but I've got that
$\vert f_k\vert \lt \frac{1}{k}$ but $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k}$ is not convergent.

I don't use Weierstraß M-Test.
$$
\begin{align*}
  \sum^{n+p}_{k=1}f_{k}(x) - \sum^{n}_{k=1}f_{k}(x) & = \sum^{n+p}_{k=n+1}f_{k}(x) \\
& = \sum^{n+p}_{k=n+1}\frac{{(-1)}^{k+1}}{x^{2}+k} \\
& = \sum^{n+p}_{k=n+1} \left(\frac{{(-1)}^{k+1}}{x^{2}+k} - \frac{{(-1)}^{k+1}}{k}\right) + \sum^{n+p}_{k=n+1}\frac{{(-1)}^{k+1}}{k} \\
& = \sum^{n+p}_{k=n+1} \frac{{(-1)}^{k}x^{2}}{(x^{2} + k)k} + \sum^{n+p}_{k=n+1}\frac{{(-1)}^{k+1}}{k}
\end{align*}
$$
According to the alternating series test, $\sum^{\infty}_{k=1}\frac{{(-1)}^{k+1}}{k}$ converges.
According to the Abel's uniform convergence test, $\sum^{\infty}_{k=1}\frac{{(-1)}^{k}x^{2}}{(x^{2} + k)k}$ converges. Here we apply Abel's test to the uniformly convergent series of functions $\sum^{\infty}_{k=1}a_{k}(x)$ and the monotonic uniformly bounded sequence of functions ${(b_{k})}^{\infty}_{k=1}$ where $a_{k}(x) = \frac{{(-1)}^{k}}{k}$ and $b_{k}(x) = \frac{x^{2}}{x^{2} + k}$ (it decreases and is contained in $[0, 1]$ hence bounded).
For every $\varepsilon > 0$

There is an integer $N_{1}$ such that for every $n\geq N_{1}, p > 0$ and for every $x\in\mathbb{R}$, $\left\vert \sum^{n+p}_{k=n+1} \frac{{(-1)}^{k}x^{2}}{(x^{2} + k)k} \right\vert < \frac{\varepsilon}{2}$.
There is an integer $N_{2}$ such that for every $n\geq N_{1}, p > 0$ and for every $x\in\mathbb{R}$, $\left\vert \sum^{n+p}_{k=n+1}\frac{{(-1)}^{k+1}}{k} \right\vert < \frac{\varepsilon}{2}$

So for every $n > N = \max\{ N_{1}, N_{2} \}, p > 0$, for every $x\in \mathbb{R}$,
$$
\begin{align*}
  \left\vert \sum^{n+p}_{k=1}f_{k}(x) - \sum^{n}_{k=1}f_{k}(x)\right\vert < \left\vert \sum^{n+p}_{k=n+1} \frac{{(-1)}^{k}x^{2}}{(x^{2} + k)k} \right\vert + \left\vert \sum^{n+p}_{k=n+1}\frac{{(-1)}^{k+1}}{k} \right\vert < \varepsilon
\end{align*}
$$
Thus $\sum^{\infty}_{k=1}f_{k}(x)$ is uniformly convergent on $\mathbb{R}$.

@Dudong Ngo Thank you! This was very helpful.
